# Calling Application.application.enable from a TitleWindow in a different mxml component

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a Flex RIA App, and in the application tag there is a button when it's pressed calls upon a TitleWindow from another .mxml file, and sets

```
application.enable = false
```

That way the user can't use any of the components in the application, and still can use the components in the TitleWindow.

The problem is when the TitleWindow is closed I want it to restore the application back to

```
application.enable = true
```

Which enables the application once again. But I can't call that code from inside the TitleWindow .mxml

How can I do it?

Here is the Source:

**Loja.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="585" height="450" xmlns:ns1="com.*">
<mx:Style source="theme/simplicitygray.css" />

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
            private var clientid = 0;       
            
            public function openWindow() : void
            {
                if (clientid == 0) 
                {
                    PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,Login,false);
                    application.enabled = false;
                } else {
                    PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,Conta,false);
                    application.enabled = false;
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    
    <mx:Panel x="10" y="40" width="565" height="400" layout="absolute">
    </mx:Panel>
    <mx:MenuBar x="10" y="10" width="565" height="22"></mx:MenuBar>
    <mx:Button x="508" y="10" label="Aceder" click="openWindow();"/>
    
</mx:Application>
```

And one of the title windows. Once they are the same.

**Login.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="350" height="200" creationComplete="centerWindow()" showCloseButton="true" close="closeWindow()" title="Login">
    
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
            public function centerWindow():void
            {
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(this);
            }
            
            public function closeWindow():void
            {
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
            
            }
            
       ]]>
       
    </mx:Script>
    
</mx:TitleWindow>
```

Comment: Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Title and body edited for better understanding.. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't know how to do it (yet) in Flex, but can you pass in a delegate or function from your main form, then have the "child" call the function when it's done with its task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`application` is a static property of the `Application` class and can be called from the `TitleWindow`

```
public function closeWindow():void
{
    PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
    Application.application.enabled = true;
}
```

BTW, There is another easier way to achieve the following:

> That way the user cant use any of the components in the application, and still can use the components in the TitleWindow.

That is to use a modal popup. Set the third parameter of the `createPopUp` to `true` and that's it - you don't have to enable/disable the application manually: flex will take care of it.

```
PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,Login, true);
```

application will automatically become functional once you call `removePopUp`.

Comment: Lool.. You can't imagine how much i've been wondering and trying to do this... and a simple true does the trick.. lol.. Thanks.

Comment: Hey thanks, was looking for this solution too! :)
Helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom events to enable this functionality, as described [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=mxmlcomponents_advanced_1.html#145191).

Essentially, you set up a custom event in the class you are calling, then create a function that runs when the event is consumed. That way your 'Loja' will know when the 'Login' is done.

Comment: Right i was trying to do a event listener to watch for the TitleWindow exit, but no luck. Any way Amarghosh last method proved simple and effective. Any way thanks Michael.