# Trapping and consuming keystrokes in Flex app

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In my Flex 4.9.1 application, at a particular point I put up a "sheet of glass" over the entire stage. It's purpose is to trap all mouse clicks until the user presses the escape key, which removes it. That part is easy and works well. It's just a FlexSprite, parented by the systemManager, which paints transparent pixels over the entire screen.

The problem is that, regardless of where the focus is before the glass is put up, or even if stage.focus is set to null, the user can press the tab key and focus text inputs beneath the glass, and enter text into them.

I tried listening for KEY_UP and KEY_DOWN events on the systemManager, with useCapture=true, and the highest possible priority (0x7FFFFF). When I get the events, I call stopPropagation(), stopImmediatePropagation(), and preventDefault() (even though the events are not cancelable) on them. Nothing works. No matter what, hitting the tab key several times will bring a textfield into focus, and typing letters will enter text into the fields.

So it appears that the text fields are not actually controlled by the key events they dispatch, as if the text is entered before the event is actually dispatched. Because presumably, if they were, they would listen at the target phase of the event flow. And as for the tab key, I have no idea why stopping its propagation doesn't prevent the focus switching.

Has anyone accomplished what I'm trying to accomplish before? If so, what worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Application.application.enabled = false;` to disable all the controls beneath the top-level Application while the "sheet of glass" is up.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1454000/514087) for more details.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar. I programmatically set the focus to a control that doesn't respond to keystrokes, then set application.tabChildren = false when the glass goes up and back to true when it's removed. As far as modal popups go (re the answer you linked), it is possible in some circumstances to get the focus behind the sheet of glass they put up, and tab around and edit things. Mostly, however, the tab key will just focus among the controls on the popup. I like your idea of disabling the application completely, however. It's simpler than my solution.